# symfony apache not sending authorization header

Tags: symfony, http-headers, apache2

I have rewrite rule in .htaccess

```
# Sets the HTTP_AUTHORIZATION header removed by Apache
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

trying to test sending a jwt authorization

```
$res = $this->client->request('GET', 
    'http://localhost/api/private', [
        'headers' => [
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer JWTTOKEN'
     ]
]);
```

`http://localhost/api/private resulted in a 401 Unauthorized response:\n{\"code\":401,\"message\":\"JWT Token not found`

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After clearing my prod cache and double checking my virtual host file settings here https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/file_permissions.htmlI started to get an empty response, The problem was that I was getting an empty response back I wasn't using guzzle correct I had to get my response from the response body and decode it

```
return new JsonResponse(json_decode($res->getBody()->getContents()));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are sending a `GET` and should probably be sending `POST`

```
$res =   $this->client->request('POST', 
'http://localhost/api/private', [
  'headers' => [
      'Authorization' => 'Bearer JWTTOKEN'
  ]
]);
```

Comment: running this curl request returns success curl --request GET   --url http://localhost/api/private   --header 'authorization: Bearer JWTTOKEN'

Comment: I am performing a GET on a resource and passing the jwt token in the header as authorization

Comment: I see, so this is *after* you have your token it's still not accepting that Header. Is `localhost` mapped to `cg-open-api.local` because it looks like that's your hostname here.